# Losing key-up event on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard, osx-yosemite

I am writing a game-like app for OS X and need to know if the left and right arrows are pressed during the game loop. I also check if the space bar is down. For this I implement

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event;
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)event
```

in my view and store the state of each key in some flags. I also check if the command button is pressed using:

```
-(void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)event;
```

If the window isn't main (another window gets focus) or resigns key (spotlight opens) I reset the flags. I do this by implementing:

```
-(void)windowDidBecomeKey:(NSNotification *)notification;
-(void)windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)notification;
-(void)windowDidResignMain:(NSNotification *)notification;
-(void)windowDidBecomeMain:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

This works almost all the time. If I press command and then space, spotlight opens and my app resigns key. However, if I hold for example the left arrow key, and first presses and holds space, then command, spotlight won't show up, but I sometimes lose the key-up event for the arrow key when I release them. It doesn't happen every time but (could depend on the release order) but it is easily reproduced in a few tries. So the key gets stuck down until the next press.

Is there another state my app enters that I'm not aware of? If not, this approach seems a bit fragile.

Is there a more robust way of checking that a key is down (that doesn't require installation of a logger tool or enabling accessibility for the app in preferences)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose I use `NSEvent`'s `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`-static method. It works while the app is active. Use `addGlobalMonitor...` for handling global events but be aware your app may be rejected from the AppStore. Here some code sample.

```
id monitor=[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:(NSEvent *)^(NSEvent *theEvent){
    if (theEvent.keyCode==/*your key code*/) // you should check the key modifiers too
    {
      // your code here
    }
    return theEvent; // you may return the event to pass the key to the receiver or nil if no need
  }];
// remove monitor
[NSEvent removeMonitor:monitor];
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome solution. Seems to work like a charm. Just to be clear: addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask would not cause rejection right?

Comment: @rasmus it wouldn't for sure.